# Java Cucumber - Run Junit Maven project in Command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line, junit, cucumber

Trying to do some automated test. I have used below commands to execute the junit file (RunnerTest.java) in command line, getting an error as "could not find class"

**Command line commands:**

```
C:\Users\username\workspace\MavenCucumberPrototype\src\test\java\com\cucumber\MavenCucumberPrototype>javac -cp "C:/cjars/*" MavenCucumberPrototype/*.java

C:\Users\username\workspace\MavenCucumberPrototype>java -classpath C:/cjars/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  src.test.java.com.cucumber.MavenCucumberPro
totype.RunnerTest
```

**Maven Project structure**

```
MavenCucumberPrototype
      -/src/main/java
         -com.cucumber.MavenCucumberPrototype
      -/src/test/java
         -com.cucumber.MavenCucumberPrototype
               -postconn.java
               -RunnerTest.java
               -Steps.java
       -/src/test/resource
               -myfeature.feature
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run Maven projects from a command line, I usually do

```
mvn clean install
```

or whatever lifecycle phase I want to execute. In your case, it might be sufficient to do

```
mvn test
```

The only imprtant thing to notice is that you must execute the command in the same directory as the `pom.xml` resides.

The error you recieve is nost likely due to a classpath that doesn't contain what you expected.